# Why i am getting " no soundcards found..." and not getting any sound?

Tags: audio, sound-card, centos-8

```
[msingh@localhost KVMfiles]$  aplay --list-devices
aplay: device_list:272: no soundcards found...

[msingh@localhost Extrasoftware]$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a3f0
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 87d3
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6001020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 6001000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

[msingh@localhost Extrasoftware]$ dmesg | grep -iC 3 snd
[    4.159787] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.159794] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.159876] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[    4.160535] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0400 -> 0402)
[    4.160664] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: number of I/O streams is 16, forcing separate stream tags
[    4.161806] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    4.161808] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.161809] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
--
[    6.339324] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    6.342194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[    6.372547] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    7.167043] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    8.168139] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000
[    9.170036] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...
[    9.180425] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[    9.180782] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
[   11.843661] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4022.0005: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
[   12.103290] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[msingh@localhost Extrasoftware]$ 

[msingh@localhost Extrasoftware]$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     69632  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         151552  2 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           90112  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                81920  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               110592  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  8 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

Also, the output is dummy
[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK, i got the working sol from here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/706602/how-do-i-get-sound-with-an-hda-card

open alsa-base.conf as root - e.g.:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
and add the following lines at the end of the file

options snd-hda-intel single_cmd=1
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
options snd-hda-intel model=basic
```